# Pagenation firestore data in python

Tags: python, django, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

Hey there i need to **Pagenate this code** can you guys please help me out i tried the docs but not able to get hold of it.

```
cases = db.collection(u'hospitals').document(request.session['hospital_email']).collection('cases').where(
            u'status', u'==', "done").where("formstatus", "==", "draft").order_by(u'date').limit(3).get()

        for i in cases:
            cases_data[i.id] = i.to_dict()
            print(cases_data[i.id], " ==>", i.to_dict())
            print("")
```

Comment: You're not calling `start_at` anywhere, which is what is required to start at a second (or later) page as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#python

Comment: can you please explain a bit more by writing an example of some sort??

Comment: The documentation page I linked is exactly about the feature you're trying to implement, and has both an explanation about the concepts and code samples for many languages (including Python). If you tried to implement what is explained/shown on that page (like `start_at`), please show the code for that. If you haven't yet, that page is the best place to start.